# Redis Hashes store with new line key value

Tags: hash, redis

I want to store data in Redis Hashes. Data is as below (Key = Value):

```
30.2.25=REF_IP
30.2.24=MY_HOST_IP
30.2.32=PEER_IP
30.2.32=IM_USER_MY_HOST
30.2.2=23992
```

Easy way to store this info in redis is below :

```
hmset info 30.2.25 REF_IP 30.2.24 MY_HOST_IP 30.2.32 PEER_IP 30.2.32 IM_USER_MY_HOST 30.2.2 23992
```

Considering I have 1000's key value and want to change few (actually so many) values in one go so searching and editing value in above command is too painful.

i want some way to execute command in below manner, that is nice formatted command with new line after every key value  :

```
hmset info
30.2.25 REF_IP
30.2.24 MY_HOST_IP
30.2.32 PEER_IP
30.2.32 IM_USER_MY_HOST
30.2.2 23992
```

Is it possible to do so ?

Currently when i copy above formatted command and paste, it ignore test after new line and giving below error which is obvious because argument is wrong due to new line.

```
hmset info
(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hmset' command
```

Can anyone help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about using redis-cli, there is no way to support this at the moment. There is an open issue for this. See https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3474

As per Redis 4.0.0, `HMSET` is considered deprecated. You should use `HSET` instead. https://redis.io/commands/hset

You can use a transaction if you want to ensure all HSETs are done at the same time, and still enter them one line at a time.

```
MULTI
HSET info 30.2.25 REF_IP
HSET info 30.2.24 MY_HOST_IP
...
EXEC
```

The commands will be sent to the server one line at a time, but they are queued and only executed at the `EXEC` command.

You may use another client, say in Python, and then do something fancier as well to condense your field-value hsets into one command.

Comment: Thanks for providing comment.